# Creating an 2-dimensional array of a struct results in crash

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am trying to generate a two-dimensional array of a `struct`, but this results in the program not launching. The window freezes and the program quits after a few seconds. Any idea why?

This is the file where I try to define the array `cells`.

```
#ifndef _FIELD_H_
    #define _FIELD_H_

class Field {
    public:
        static const int minX = -400;
        static const int maxX = 400;
        static const int minY = 0;
        static const int maxY = 400;

        Field();

    private:
        struct absCell {
            int material;
            float health;
        } cells[maxX - minX + 1][maxY - minY + 1];
};

#endif
```

The program is able to run when I remove these four lines:

```
        struct absCell {
            int material;
            float health;
        } cells[maxX - minX + 1][maxY - minY + 1];
```

Any idea how this happens? Any help is appreciated!

### Update

Okay, apparently the problem is that this array gets quite big. Maybe you can help me to optimize this.

Material has to be an int between 0 and 10.
Health has to be a float between 0 and 1 with a maximum of 2 fractional digits.

How can I limit the size of these vars?

### Update 2

Mark B suggested the use of `vectors` while itwasntpete suggested the use of pointers, new and delete. Where is the difference, what are the advantages and disadvantages of these two methods? Thanks again!

Comment: Looks perfectly valid to me. Have you tried debugging it? The issue is most certainly somewhere else, not in the code you've shown us.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with that.  The problem is probably elsewhere and it just happens to show up when you make that change.  Try to create a SSCCE of the problem:  http://sscce.org/

Comment: I'm going to dust off my aging and somewhat foggy crystal ball to suggest in `main()` you have something like `Field fld;` (worse, an *array* of `Field`. If so, note that this structure is defining a fixed stack-bound array of around 800x400 members, or 320000 `int` and `float` values. Assuming each is 4 bytes, thats 256000 bytes, or approximately **2.44 MB** of stack space *per Field object*. In short, I think it quite likely you're blowing out your stack. Please show us where you're *using* `Field`, specifically where-and-how the variables of type `Field` are defined.

Comment: I estimate your class will need around 2.5 Gb of memory for each instance. That's not an impossibly big amount but it is quite a lot. Have you tried reducing the size of the array?

Comment: good example for a [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I only need one instance of this class, but I can not reduce the size of the array. Maybe the size of the `struct` could be reduced? I need this array to store the status of a games environment. Could you tell me how to use the heap to store this? I have to store this data from the beginning of the program until the end.

Comment: How to use the heap? Just use vectors instead of an array, and use unsigned char instead of int and float (as Mark B says in his answer).

Comment: You say you cannot reduce the size of the array... Are you sure about that -- do you really have hundreds of thousands of unique values? If most of the values are the same or if they are somehow calculatable then there's no need to allocate a massive matrix -- a dictionary or some other sparse data structure would do fine.

Comment: @jku The values are not calculatable and they are very likely to change constantly. There are about a thousand different values (Health 0 to 100 for about 10 different materials). How can I use another data structure than my array here?

Comment: what I mean is for example this: if most of the cells at any given time are of a default value, then you could store the non-default values in a dictionary (and use the default value if the cell is not in the dictionary). For your situation -- a game, lot of change in the cells -- this might not be applicable though.

Comment: @LarsEbert Answer to update2, vectors are easier, pointers are very difficult for a newbie, as any amount of reading of this forum would tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on update note:

The first thing you can do is easily optimize your struct for space by using `unsigned char` for each attribute, using a fixed-point representation for your existing float (for example 0.23 would be stored as the integer 23).

Then store the structs on the heap with vector instead of an array:

```
    struct absCell {
        unsigned char material;
        unsigned char health;
    };
    std::vector<std::vector<absCell> > cells_;
```

Then set up the constructor:

```
Field() : cells_(maxX - minX + 1, std::vector<absCell>(maxY - minY + 1)) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are allocating 801 * 401 (=321201) elements of `struct absCell` on the stack. Assuming you have a 32bit machine it is 2569608 Byte (~2.45 MB). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program) it is blowing up your stack.

Move the elements to heap like:

```
class Field {
public:
    static const int minX = -400;
    static const int maxX = 400;
    static const int minY = 0;
    static const int maxY = 400;

    Field() {
        cells = new absCell*[maxX - minX + 1];
        for(int i=0; i<maxX - minX + 1; i++)
            cells[i] = new absCell[maxY - minY + 1];
    }

    ~Field() {
        for(int i=0; i<maxX - minX + 1; i++)
            delete[] cells[i];

        delete[] cells;
    }

private:
    struct absCell {
        unsigned char material;
        unsigned char health;
    }**cells;
};
```

### Update

Material and health can be saved in a `char`. Accessing health you have to recalculate it:

```
put -> x*100
get -> x/100
```

### Update 2

Except you have some reasons, using a vector is most likely the better option, as Mark B 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18923910/1810087) describes.

Comment: Are there any (dis-)advantages compared to using `vectors` like Mark B suggested?

Comment: @Lars Ebert This version can result in a double delete/undefined version if a `Field` is ever copied.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you're hitting the stack limit. When you make that array like it is its trying to put 801*401*8 bytes on your stack. I did a quick compile and was having crashes until I lowered the numbers for your various mins and maxes.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your snippet right way, you're trying to create an array. Allocation of the array is stack-based, with more than 2 Mb size required. There may be a chance that your stack has less than that 2Mb available, thus the code crashes right at the moment you're entering the function.

Try to allocate the same array dinamically.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my question. Do you know how to optimize the `struct`?