# segmentation fault 11 in C++ on Mac

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When I try to run this

```
int N=10000000;
short res[N];
```

I get segmentation fault 11

when I change to

```
int N=1000000;
short res[N];
```

it works fine

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables)

Comment: So, what is your issue?  You are trying to allocate a buffer on the stack that is probably too large for the environment.  There is a limit on stack size.  If you need to create a buffer that big, it sholud be via new() on the heap.

Comment: @YuHao Don't you mean [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: possible want to read [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes) or [Creating an 2-dimensional array of a struct results in crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923339/creating-an-2-dimensional-array-of-a-struct-results-in-crash)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've exceeded your stack space given by the OS. If you need more memory, the easiest way is to allocate it dynamically:

```
int N=1000000;
short* res = new short[N];
```

However, `std::vector` is preferred in this context, because the above requires you to `free` the memory by hand.

```
int N = 1000000;
std::vector<short> res (N);
```

If you can use C++11, you can possibly save some fraction of time by using `unique_ptr` array specialization, too:

```
std::unique_ptr<short[]> res (new short[N]);
```

Both of the automatic methods above can still be used with familiar `res[index]` syntax thanks to overloaded `operator[]`, but to get the raw pointer for memory operations you'd need `res.data()` with `vector` or `res.get()` with `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't allocate all that on the stack. Try `short* res = new short[10000000];` and don't forget to clean up.

Alternatively, you can use `std::vector<short> res(10000000);`