# Why is the following code causing segmentation fault 11?

Tags: c

The following code produces segmentation fault 11 when run, I couldn't figure out why. Could anyone offer some insight? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int s, e;
int i,j;
typedef struct coordinate {
   int x;
   int y;
} coordinate;

typedef struct cell {
   int altitude;
   coordinate lowest_neighbor;
   int visited;
   int basin;
} cell;

cell cells[1000][1000];
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
        cells[i][j].altitude = 9;
    }
}
printf("%d", cells[0][0].altitude);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Duplicate of [Creating an 2-dimensional array of a struct results in crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923339/creating-an-2-dimensional-array-of-a-struct-results-in-crash) (and *many* others).

Answer (score 1):

Because this:

```
cell cells[1000][1000];
```

is blowing out your stack. Assuming a four-byte `int` with no padding in the structures, that array takes up *twenty million* bytes, quite a lot for a stack.

As a quick fix (for this program anyway), try out:

```
static cell cells[1000][1000];
```

which, for many implementations, will take it off the stack.

There are downsides to this approach in general as that means there is only *one* copy of the array, not one per function call or thread, but that won't matter here since your program only creates it once anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. How would this problem be solved with dynamic memory allocation? Would that be the most appropriate approach?