# C++ Vector appear to be faster than C Array (Time). Why ?

Tags: xcode, performance, debugging, memory, vector

Hello I have seen that [C++ Vector vs Array (Time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932222/c-vector-vs-array-time).
On my mac the vector take times to be defined but after the comparison give vector for winner.
How it works ?
I was said int[] are faster than dynamic vector ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define N (100000000)
//int sd[N];
int main() {
    clock_t start;
    double temps;
    static int sd[N];
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned long i=0 ; i < N ; i++){
        if(sd[i]==3)
            ;
    }
    temps = (clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
    printf("Time: %f ms\n",temps);
    vector<int>vd(N);
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned long i=0 ; i < N ; i++){
        if(vd[i]==3)
            ;
    }
    temps = (clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
    printf("Time: %f ms\n",temps);
    while (1)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

I have those results :

- Time: 422.87400 ms
- Time: 300.84700 ms
  Even if it begining with vector, vector appear to be faster than c array.

Thank You for your explaination.

Another question : in xcode, why i see memory used by declation vector and for static c array I have to go all the memory cells as in the code (for ... if(sd[i]...)

Thank You for your explaination.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.  Because your array allocation is declared `static`, it's no different than a global variable as far as how the compiler allocates it.  Hence, it has to be paged in differently from the vector declared on the stack that uses allocated heap memory.  In any case allocating a consecutive array of 100M integers suggests a bad design.  What are you ***really trying to do*** ?

Comment: Hello, it's just to have a big array.<br>Why it is not a bood concept ?<br>Multi array dimension is better ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have remarqued that if i initialize all the c array cells at 0 (for example or 6...) the c array will be faster or equal vector.

```
int main() {
    clock_t start;
    double temps;
    static int sd[N];
    for (unsigned long i=0 ; i < N ; i++){
        sd[i]=0;
    }

    start = clock();
    //puts("initialized");
    for (unsigned long i=0 ; i < N ; i++){
        if(sd[i]==3)
            ;
    }
    temps = (clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
    printf("Time: %f ms\n",temps);
    //puts("initialized");
    vector<int>vd(N);
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned long i=0 ; i < N ; i++){
        if(vd[i]==3)
            ;
    }
    temps = (clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
    printf("Time: %f ms\n",temps);

    while (1)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

And I will see the memory used in xcode with the initialization at 0 of all cells c array.

So another question , why it is more rapid when you initialize in this case (or in general) ?