# unable to initialize double array

Tags: c++, double

I have 4 gig RAM and the following lines that throws a stackoverflow exception:

```
int main()
{
     double X[4096*512], Y[4096*512], Z[4096*512];
     return 0;
}
```

each double takes 8 bytes space, so my three arrays should be 3*4096*512*8/1024/1024 = 48 Mbyte big, can somebody explain the error or is 48 Mbyte too much to handle?

Comment: Too much on the stack. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program

Comment: another thing to keep in mind regardless how you allocate is to split up the memory so that it is not continuous e.g. `double* X[4096]`

Comment: @Claptrap Depends? You are saying that s/he should allocate one array per row to prevent fragmentation, but these arrays are small enough that memory fragmentation shouldn't be a problem...managing, copying, and traversing 512 different buffers on the other hand can be super annoying and unless you're careful requires 2 memory hits per-lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring in the stack, normally the stack in OS are limited (eg: 1MB), you could expanded when compiling (eg: in GCC use `-Wl,stack_size,134217728` 128Mb) but don't recommend.

Better use `std::vector<double>`.

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
     std::vector<double> X(4096*512), Y(4096*512), Z(4096*512);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the overhead of std::vector, you can allocate the arrays on the heap

```
double *myArray = new double[SIZE];
```

and remember to free them.

```
delete [] myArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment (not a thorough description, you should do more research), there are two types of memory, the "stack" and the "heap". The stack is the local working memory of a piece of software, while the heap is the big pool. The stack holds all the local variables of a function call. Anything local declared within the function will be stored on the stack. The stack had a nifty property that it can be "pushed": when we call the next function, we go further down the stack and start over. But this means that the amount of stack memory needs to be generally reserved for the lifetime of a program, so we limit it to a small amount: general 1 to a few megabytes.

When you run out of stack memory, you get a "Stack Overflow" ("Now thats what that means!")

The heap is kindof the rest of the memory. The heap is where the program stores any dynamic memory and (possibly, it can be more complicated) global variables. The heap is where things like `malloc` and `new` puts its memory.

Whenever you declare a local variable, it is stored on the stack. This isn't a problem for small variables, but arrays like the ones you have get HUGE easy.

If you don't want to worry about `new` or `malloc` you can use things like `std::vector`, which will put the large amount of data on the heap while giving you local variable semantics.

Again, this is "basic programming" so you should get really familiar with this subject.