# Why this code raise to EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW?

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

So i write the code.

I dont understand why this is going to EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char data[2048][2048] = {{0}};
    cout << "test";
    return 0;
}
```

even if i dont inilitialize

```
char data[2048][2048];
```

situation is the same on both cases.

```
Running "main.exe", press ESC to terminate...        
Crash                                                
  EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW                           
  time consumed: 0.01 sec                            
  time passed:   0.08 sec                            
  peak memory:   4395008 bytes
```

Comment: 4Mb is larger than the default stack size. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program

Comment: because `data` is too big to be "automatic storage duration"

Comment: Because data is too big to fit on the stack. Make it a vector.

Comment: how can i extend stack size via gcc?

Comment: @Daniel: Don't do that.  Move the array to dynamic memory instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is too big to keep it on the stack. You should use dynamic storage duration.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> data(new char[2048*2048]);
```

However, if you really want or must keep it on the stack, here is a gcc flag to change the default stack size:

**--stack,4194304** where 4194304 is stack size in bytes

Comment: Or you can increase the amount of stack space allocated.

Comment: please do not recommend raw allocation for something that is better solved with a `std::vector`

Comment: @Mgetz I think you should reconsider what did you write in terms of comparison std::vector and std::unique_ptr.

Comment: @szulak What are you arguing? That thrown exception doesn't leak `data`? That raw pointer isn't harder to use incorrectly than `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`? Guess what. It does, and it is.

Comment: I've shown two options, so OP could choose the one he/she wants. Anyway, I edited my answer and removed raw allocation.