# Array size causing C to crash

Tags: c, arrays

I am working to make a large array of structs in C. I need the array to hold over 1 million struct instances. However when the array size gets above a couple hundred thousand the program crashes. It runs fine for the first bit then it crashes. I am running Windows 7 with 6 gb of RAM.

What is the root cause of this problem? Below is the code

```
struct Job {
   unsigned long id;
   unsigned int num_preds;
   unsigned int resources;
   unsigned int* pred_array;
};

int main()
{
    //Counter and loop variables (Do not use for any other purpose)
    unsigned int i,j,k,count;
    unsigned long height,num_jobs;
    // This is our input section
    height = 1000;
    //Calculate the number of jobs
    num_jobs = (height+1)*height*0.5;
    printf("%d \n",num_jobs);

    struct Job jobs[num_jobs];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if they have improved things in the last 10 years, but it used to be you had to increase a compiler setting in Visual Studio to allow programs to use more stack space.

Comment: It is C. You have to manage your memory yourself

Comment: There are quite a number of possible alternatives to the selected duplicate, but this is one of the earliest questions that is covering the same topic.  Search for '[c] stack size limit' to find others -- 75 or so other questions.

Answer (score 4):

The stack has a limited size. Try allocating large arrays on the heap using malloc.

Comment: It is 4 MiB or less on Windows, isn't it?  It's 8 MiB on Unix, usually.  It can be changed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program

Comment: It says 1 MB. 1 million objects will fill that pretty easily.

Comment: putting that much stuff on the stack is "doing it wrong"

Comment: Quite. Indeed. Forsooth.