# Getting Segmentation fault (Core dumped) error while executing the C++ program

Tags: c++

Below is the code I am trying to run, I keep getting the error Segmentation fault.
Added Compare. In the below program I need to consider an array of 5000000 or less(this is n) numbers and implement quicksort on those numbers.

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  const double *da = (const double *) a;
  const double *db = (const double *) b;

  return (*da > *db) - (*da < *db);
  }
int main(){

int n = rand()% 5000000;
double arr[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    arr[i] = (double)rand();
}
qsort(arr,n, sizeof(double), compare);
 for (int  i=0;i<n;i++){
     cout<<arr[i]<<"\n";
 }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: Probably too big....

Comment: Can you show us the code for `compare` too?

Comment: added the code for compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with the `double arr[n]` syntax you are allocating the array on the stack.

Now, the stack is a limited resource, and `n` can grow up to almost 5 megabytes, which is way beyond the [normal size of the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program)

You should allocate the array on the heap with

```
double * arr = new double[n];
```

and then free it at the end of the function with

```
delete[] arr;
```

Comment: delete []arr I guess is better

Comment: How do I modify to fix the error? I have to consider an array and the length of the array can go upto 5000000

Comment: @KSK use the heap, not the stack

Comment: Or perhaps use `std::vector`

Comment: @johnbakers I am at beginner level of C++ programming, can you tell how can I change from stack to heap.

Comment: @KSK the others on this page have already shown you how to do that

Answer (score 2):

1) `rand` usually cannot generate numbers that large. It is commongly capped around 32k

2) `double arr[n];` is not legal if n is not a compile-time constant. You are probably using  unportable compiler extention.

3) Stack space (where arr resides) is usually very limited. I doubt it can accomodate so much data which is the reason to crash.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?  I have to consider an array and the length of the array can go upto 5000000

Comment: @KSK (1) [use c++11 `random` library to generate your number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). (2) and (3): allocate array dynamically in heap space.

Comment: 1) really depends on system, windows uses INT16_MAX standard gnu header uses INT32_MAX

Comment: if you don't have c++11, you can also use multiple random calls to get more bits

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a very partial answer but I can't add comments (low reputation...)
Still, there should be a RAND_MAX value defined in stdlib (0x7FFF in my case)
So to my understanding rand() returns a value between 0 and 32767.
If you want a value between 0 and 5000000 you can try

```
unsigned int n = ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX) * 5000000;
double * arr = new double[n];
...
delete[] arr;
```

Also, check that your compare structure is a strict comparator.

Hope it helps