# large arrays, std::vector and stack overflow

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, stack

I have a program that is reading data from large arrays, I initially divided the program in two separate projects in Visual Studio and each one separately worked fine, but when I tried to put them together the program acted funny skipping some steps while debugging. I'm very new on C++ so I started doing some research and I found that maybe I was filling the stack with those huge arrays and that I should try to put them on the heap instead.

I decided to change each of the arrays for a `std::vector` and initialize them this way:

```
std::vector<double> meanTimeAO = { 0.4437, 0.441, 0.44206, 0.44632, 0.4508, 0.45425,...}
```

But after changing all of the arrays now when I try to compile the compiler crashes with a stack overflow, I thought I was liberating memory space from the stack by changing the arrays as a vector but it seems I had the opposite results, why is that??

and how should I deal with these big arrays? (they are fixed never changing values or size)

Comment: Have you tried making the arrays just `static const float meanTimeAO[] = { 0.4437, 0.441, 0.44206, 0.44632, 0.4508, 0.45425, ... }`? That shouldn't put them on the stack if you do it like that.

Comment: Put the arrays with initializer outside of a function

Comment: A solution to the fixed size in all arrays is using the data structure called Linked List where each element stores an object referring to the next successive element. Or you can always redefine your vector with a new size by instantiating a new vector and copying all elements but this time with a greater size.

Comment: @MosheRabaev: The array's fixed size isn't a problem of the OP; it's an invariant. Using linked lists (or even a `std::vector`) is unnecessary here and would be circuitous.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but... If the intent is to place the arrays directly in the heap, wouldn't the simplest solution be to dynamically allocate them?

Comment: @NonCreature0714: Not necessarily. The array needs to be initialized with values, and those values need to be stored in the program somewhere. If the array is a constant array, then there's no sense in dynamically allocating it and then initializing it with values that are already stored somewhere in the program. Instead, it's better to skip the allocation and just use the values that are already being stored in the program.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 OP only wanted to use the heap to try to solve the stack overflow problem. It wasn't a primary goal. The solutions of Cornstalks and/or Ajay are much simpler because the data is fixed and needs to be initialized with values. They end up in global [non-stack] scope without the messiness of using the heap here.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks to you both for explaining, that clears things up for me. I was a little puzzled with the question/answer, being fairly new to C++; I understand better why their solutions are very good.

Comment: I love when someone asks a question about stack overflow on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11):

As @Ajay's answer and @Cornstalks comment correctly point out you can avoid the stack and the heap entirely by using a `static` or `constexpr` qualifier on your array

```
const static std::array<float, 1000000> a1 = {}; // OK
constexpr    std::array<float, 1000000> a2 = {}; // OK in C++11 onwards
```

This stores the array in the data initialized section of your memory ([good explanation here](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/teoX.pdf)). The `const` serves only to disallow modification of `a1`, and is not needed to avoid stack overflow. Variables declared as `constexpr` are also automatically `const` and hence do not need the qualifier.

Note: You can also achieve the effects of `static` by making your array(s) global variables, although I would **not** recommend this.

### Program Stack Overflow

If your data is non-static you should use `std::vector` (or other kinds of heap allocated memory) when the number of elements is very large.

```
std::array<float, 1000000> a = {};   // Causes stack-overflow on 32-bit MSVS 2015
std::vector<float> v(1000000);       // OK
```

This is because the default stack size is ~1MB, and 1 million floats requires ~4MB. The size of the heap is limited by your system's available memory (RAM). [More on the stack and heap here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap?rq=1).

The downsides of `std::vector` are that it's a little slower than `std::array`(heap memory allocation, deallocation and access is all slower than that of the stack), and that it's not a fixed size. However you can declare your `std::vector` as `const` to prevent yourself (or someone else) from accidentally altering its size or elements.

```
const std::vector<float> v = {...};
```

Now as to why your `std::vector`s are causing stack overflows is a bit of a mystery. However while `std::vector` allocates its elements on the heap, it also allocates a pointer (4 Bytes on 32-bit and 8-Bytes on 64-bit) on the stack. So if you have over ~250,000 `std::vector`s all in scope at once, this will also cause a stack-overflow (or ~125,000 on 64-bit systems).

### Compiler Stack Overflow

The compiler, like any program, allocates memory - some of which will be on the stack. The official error for a compiler stack overflow on MSVC is [Fatal Error C1063](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229021(v=vs.60).aspx).

Given that your debugger is behaving oddly, my advice would be to try and isolate the problematic code by manually splitting your code up into modular units and compiling them individually. It's possible that a small amount of code could be responsible for the error, by eating up lots of stack e.g. by recursively generating a large number of functions.

Alternatively, it may be that your code is so inherently complicated that it naturally requires more memory than the stack has. In which case, splitting your code up will still be of benefit but you could also try [increasing the default stack size of MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx).

### Improving Your Code

To improve your code you could try splitting your data up into chunks. For example you could: read in ~256 KB worth of the array, process it, write the array back to file, then move onto to the next 256 KB. You could further choose the size of the chunk to be less than the size of your L1 cache (so it could all be stored at once) which would improve performance by minimizing cache misses.

### Notes

1. MSVS 2015 (update 2) produces an internal compiler error when compiling

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <array>
   int main()
   {
        constexpr std::array<int, 1000000> a = {};
        return 0;
   }
   ```

   The `static const` variant works fine, and if I move `a` outside main (making it a global variable) then it also works fine.
2. Not having a chkstk.asm is unusual. Mine is located at 
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\i386\chkstk.asm`. If you're missing it, then maybe try reinstalling MS Visual Studio.

Comment: I've compiled the same on VS2015 itself, and it compiles fine. Hope you have RTM. Also, the table itself says `constexpr` is supported.

Comment: Thanks @Ajay! I just tested your code with a new project in VS2015 and it works perfectly. I've no idea what went wrong before, in my previous project. Sorry I meant that "Extended constexpr" isn't supported (under the "C++ 14 Core Language Features" header) - but I think I confused the two, as in I thought one needed C++14 to declare variables as constexpr.

Comment: Ah, I've discovered the source of the error. When I test your code as it, it works perfectly. However it's only allocating 6 floats (ignoring the ...). When I try `constexpr float a[1000000] = {};` or `constexpr std::array<float, 1000000> a = {};` I get "An internal compiler error has occured", although I'm not sure why. For small sizes of arrays it works fine.

Comment: Sorry all, my bad - I was initializing the array inside my main function. Now that I've moved the array outside the main function, it works perfectly.

Comment: Regarding default stack size: 1MB is already a lot of stack (windows, right?). My systems (Linux, BSD) are around 8 KB.

Comment: @DanielJour Yes, that number is specific to Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 on Windows, which I assume the OP uses because he mentions that his projects are in Visual Studio. You're right, different systems have very different stack sizes (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1825996/6367128) for more on this).

Answer (score 9):

If the array is of fixed size, and its elements don't change, there is no real need to use `vector`. You could use `std::array`, array of `const` or `constexpr` instead.

```
constexpr float meanTimeAO[] = { 0.4437f, 0.441f, 0.44206f, 0.44632f, 0.4508f, 0.45425f,...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointing out maybe a couple things overlooked in the above answers:

1. "program acted funny skipping some steps while debugging".  OP, can you provide some more details on what you mean?  Perhaps, you were debugging a release build, and as you step through the code you observe that the line of code being executed is not the one you expect to execute next (which is perfectly correct behaviour for a release build with compiler optimisations).
2. The question stated that the *compiler* crashed with a stack overflow.  Not the executed program.  So the problem is a compiler problem.  Sure, changing the code might make the compiler not crash, but the comment above about allocating std::vector on the stack is unrelated to what might cause the *compiler* to crash.

Suggestions: you could try seeing if there are any known bugs in the version of compiler you are using (i.e. see if your compiler vendor has released a more recent version which might address the compiler crashing).

Also, specifically picking up on your "they are never changing in value or size" comment, try putting your data into static const double arrays, rather than std::vectors (or even linked lists).  An unchanging statically-allocated readonly linked list is sortof a waste of time when you probably should just use double[] . static const data is initialized at compile/link time rather than runtime, and exists in its own memory area (neither stack nor heap, strictly speaking).

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone for your responses... let me clarify the first points I made... when I am debugging my program if I go to "step into"  step by step it keeps searching for a file called chkstk.asm that isn't there. If i go "step over" in that place the program continues but all the initialization variables steps at the beginning of my program are skipped. Looking into the chkstk.asm  on this site is why I concluded I am having problems with my stack full and that is why I tried to change the bigger arrays to vectors

Comment: with respect to point 2, the compiler crashes with an error saying Compiler limit reached stack overflow.