# Default stack size

Tags: c++, c, arrays, windows, codeblocks

How can I increase the stack size in Code::Blocks?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program%20%22%22) and it says default stack size in VS is 1MB. Now as far as I am concerned, it has nothing to do with VS and stack size is OS dependent. In my win10 case it is 1MB.

[This](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=7556.0%20%22%22)  seems a little bit outdated as following this: `project->build options->linker settings->other linker options` doesn't exist no more.

There's no build under project bar.

Anyway, I need to increase my stack size so I can declare a huge two dimensional char array and benefit from cache. Like `arr[1000][1000]`. As it will be on contiguous memory unlike `char* arr[100]` which will point to 1000 different memory addresses containing the 1000 bytes.

I'm using Windows 10 mingw compiler.

Comment: There's nothing magical about the memory on the stack.  It won't be any faster than memory allocated from the heap.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes but having the whole thing in a contiguous slot will gain from cache. Unlike when its allocated on heap using `malloc` then I'll have 1000 different segmants and more cache miss.

Comment: Oh, I see - you think you'd have to allocate 1000 different 1000-byte blocks.  You don't.  Just allocate a single block of a million bytes, and cast it as an 2-dimensional array.  You can't do that in Java, say, but it works fine in C/C++.

Comment: The syntax is a little tricky though: `char (*arr)[1000] = (char(*)[1000])malloc(1000*1000);`

Comment: @HarryJohnston an explanation please :) ? is this a way to allocate 1000 blocks of 1000 bytes and have them in a contiguous memory block ? if so, why not use a 2'd array in first place ? thanks for the comment though!

Comment: Increasing the default stack size is an inefficient way of doing this, because *every* thread will have a big stack even though only one thread needs it.  In many situations it will make more sense to use a static array, but I assumed you'd have already done that if it was appropriate.  I'm not sure what you need explained, the code in my comment allocates a single million-byte block and tells the compiler to use it as a 2D array.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I understand that now :). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default size comes from the .exe, not the OS.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The default size for the reserved and initially committed stack memory
>   is specified in the executable file header.

Specifically, the stack reserve and commit sizes are specified in the [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) structure in a PE file. This can usually be set to a specific value with a linker parameter. With the MinGW toolchain you can try something like `-Wl,--stack,52428800` as a gcc parameter. This option might exist in the IDE you are using, just look for build and/or linker settings.

This applies to the first thread, other threads can override the default if you specify a non-zero value when you call `CreateThread`.

Comment: But in this article http://gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html says it is **OS dependent**... ?

Comment: There's nothing in this answer that contradicts that. On the Windows OS, this particular header is used to specify a stack size.  Only Windows uses PE files for its binaries, so other operating systems will behave differently.