# Getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to read text file into array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, file, exc-bad-access

I'm writing this using Xcode on my mac.

The file is definitely the correct location, and it opens it fine. That's not the problem.

I'm aiming to get a text file of words to be read in, and stored in the array `list` for future use, so the array acts as a dictionary.

However no cigar. Any help would be great!

```
#define MAX_WORDS 300000
#define MAX_BUFFER 50

int create_dictionary(void) {

    FILE *fp = fopen("/Users/numberjak/Documents/Home/Projects/Python/anagram/words.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: File not found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char list[MAX_WORDS][MAX_BUFFER];

    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(list[i], MAX_BUFFER, fp) != NULL) {
        printf(list[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your `list` array blows up the stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program
Does it work if you tune down `MAX_WORDS` to say 1000?

Comment: Yes it does, what’s happening there? How can I fix it?

Comment: You declare `list` array on stack which has limited size. You may want to consider allocating it on heap with `malloc`.

Comment: Oh okay! Great thank you!

Comment: regarding: `printf(list[i]);`  This is a security risk.  Suggest using: `printf( "%s\n", list[i] );`