# Stack allocation of character array causes Segmentation Fault while Heap allocation does not

Tags: memory, segmentation-fault, heap-memory

I am new to programming and wonder why I get a Segmentation Fault when I declare a character array on the stack and not when I do it on the heap.I looked up the article for Stack vs Heap allocation but do not see why this would fail.

The below gives the segmentation fault on the memset

```
char space[(2*len + 1) * cnt];
memset(space, 0, (2*len + 1) * cnt);
```

The below works fine

```
char *space = (char *)malloc((2*len + 1) * cnt);
memset(space, 0, (2*len + 1) * cnt);
```

In my case len = 999 and cnt = 9999. I am guessing the large memory allocation might be a reason caused by possible stack fragmentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running on a small platform where the available stack space is less than (2*999+1)*9999 = 19,988,001 bytes? Or maybe your compiler defaults to a stack smaller than that? For example, this thread says that Visual Studio's default stack size is only 1MB: [C/C++ maximum stack size of program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program).

Comment: A cat /proc/<pid>/limits shows this for Stack size - Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes

Comment: @PeterJ The default stack size on Linux is 8MiB, and you are exceeding that. Use `ulimit -s unlimited` to increase available stack.

Comment: Thanks @EmployedRussian I did before checking your response :)