# Why is the program not working for an array but works fine when it is a normal variable?

Tags: c, arrays, double, codeblocks

I'm trying to write a code that takes a couple of inputs, calls upon the function to calculate a value, assigns that value to a variable and print that variable. I actually need to form a matrix out of these values.

When I assign the value to a regular variable, the program does what is expected. So if the main function is like this:

```
//some user-defined functions that the main function calls//

void main()
{
    int m,n;
    printf("Row: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Column: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    double k,A;
    printf("k= ");
    scanf("%lf",&k);
    A=matrix_element(m,n,k);
    printf("%lf",A);
}
```

The output is correct:

```
Row: 1
Column: 1
k= 1
2.275499
Process returned 8 (0x8)   execution time : 5.974 s
Press any key to continue.
```

But when I try to assign the value to an element in an array, the program doesn't work. I mean to say, if the main function is like this:

```
//some user-defined functions that the main function calls//

void main()
{
    int m,n;
    printf("Row: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Column: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    double k,A[800][800];
    printf("k= ");
    scanf("%lf",&k);
    A[m][n]=matrix_element(m,n,k);
    printf("%lf",A[m][n]);
}
```

The program does nothing:

```
Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 2.207 s
Press any key to continue.
```

What is happening and how can I fix it? I have to take the values in an 800x800 2D array because my end goal is to put it in a for loop and form a matrix of these dimensions.

For those who want to see the MCVE code, here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double S(int g, int i) //Scattering Cross-section//
{
    double x;
    x=2;
    return x;
}

double D(int g, int i) //Diffusion co-efficient//
{
    double x;
    x=2;
    return x;
}

double A(int g, int i) //Absorption Cross-section//
{
    double x;
    x=2;
    return x;
}

double vF(int g, int i) //velocity x Fission Cross-section//
{
    double x;
    x=2;
    return x;
}

double F(int g, int i) //Fission Cross-section//
{
    double x;
    x=2;
    return x;
}

double h(int i) //Height//
{
    double x;
    x=2;
    return x;
}

double matrix_element(int m, int n, double k)
{
    int g,i;
    double C;
    C=1;
    return C;
}

void main()
{
    int m,n;
    printf("Row: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Column: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    double k,A[800][800];
    printf("k= ");
    scanf("%lf",&k);
    A[m][n]=matrix_element(m,n,k);
    printf("%lf",A[m][n]);
}
```

This one produces the same problem.

Comment: `double A[800][800];` has 5MB and is on the stack. It is probably too big for your stack.

Comment: Where is the definition of `matrix_element`?

Comment: Does it work if you move `double A[800][800];` out of `main` so it's not on the stack?

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where is the function `matrix_element` defined?

Comment: @Broman if you're interested, I'm posting the full code in the next answer.

Comment: Why not just `"Edit"` your question and ***Add*** the new information at the end?

Comment: @AmitHasanArpon Don't post full code. Post a [mcve] and post it in the question.

Comment: @Blaze, how do I do that?

Comment: First fix a [mcve] and then click edit to edit the question.

Comment: You missed the "minimal" part. I'm pretty sure you can remove 80% of that code and still reproduce your problem.

Comment: The functions S, D, vF, h, A and F could probably be replaced by dummy values.

Comment: @Broman Well, it seems to be the A[800][800] thing, because when I try with A[100][100], it works fine. But my project requires the 800x800 array. Suggestions? And if you must have the minimal code, I can post that too. Doing it now.

Comment: @AmitHasanArpon It's not so much that I need it right now. I'm just teaching you in how to properly ask a question here. And you would be surprised how many times you realize what the problem is during the creations of a mcve ([mcve]). Very often that leads to that I don't even have to post a question here. It's a great debugging tool.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited and posted it now. Please don't be offended. And help! @Broman

Comment: @AmitHasanArpon I posted an answer to explain that, hope it helps

Comment: @AmitHasanArpon I'm not offended. Asking questions takes some time to learn. Actually, this code would probably be enough to demonstrate your problem: `void main()
{
    double A[800][800];
    A[0][0]=42.0;
    printf("%lf",A[0][0]);
}`

Comment: @Blaze that worked! Thanks man! You saved me from my professor's wrath ^_^

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to put the array in the global scope instead of declaring it inside of a function:

```
double A[800][800];

void main()
{
    int m, n;
    printf("Row: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Column: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double k;
    printf("k= ");
    scanf("%lf", &k);
    A[m][n] = 123.0; // for this example you can replace "matrix_element" with a dummy value
    printf("%lf", A[m][n]);
}
```

This way it is in a seperate storage location instead of on the stack. `double` often is 8 bytes, so `A[800][800]` is 4.88 MB big. That's huge for the stack and may cause a stack overflow.If it's global that shouldn't be a problem unless you're on an embedded system, an old machine or an other system where  memory is very limited. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825964/10411602) for more details on how much memory there is for the stack, but typically, a well-written program shouldn't come close to that.

Comment: Global scope variables are stored in a seperate storage location for Static and Global variables. They are not stored in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D array `A` is mostly likely causing a stack overflow due to its size. Large local variables (i.e. variables with automatic storage duration) should be avoided. Instead use dynamic allocation.

For a dynamic allocated 2D array do like this:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 800

...

double (*A)[ARR_SIZE] = malloc(ARR_SIZE * sizeof *A);

...

A[m][n] = 42.0;

...

free(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides defining the matrix as a global variable or allocating it from a heap using malloc, you **can** declare a bigger stack for your program. However, the steps is OS/compiler dependent. You will need to consult your compiler documents for detail.

Each method (global, heap, and stack) has its strength/weakness. You should choose the best solution for your needs, even if they all solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be the size of the allocation on the stack. The application is crashing at

```
double k,A[800][800];
```

Because this array is allocated at the start of the program and the size of the array would be 800*800*8 = 5MB. Which is too big for your stack.

The code works when it is written as:

```
double* A = malloc(sizeof(double)*m*n);
```

This would allocated memory on the heap and would make it work.

Comment: `double* A = new double[m*n];` in a C program?

Comment: Don’t cast the return value from malloc.

Comment: The problem does seem to be the size of the allocation. If I try it with A[100][100], it works fine. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: In C it is bad practice to cast the result of a call to `malloc`. It serves no purpose because `void*` will convert implicitly and it can hide mistakes such as forgetting to include `stdlib.h`. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/139746 )

Comment: With `double* A = malloc(sizeof(double)*m*n);`, The `A` variable won't be accessible in A[x][y] form.

Comment: As has been said before it is the size of your stack that is the problem. Just allocate it on the heap. This also makes it possible to easily share the large dataset with other functions and modules without constantly copying it through the function scopes.

Comment: @PascalCuoq my bad. I usally use C++ and my qt project was in C++ so it warned me. I fixed the answer.