# Caught Fatal signal 11 just on a test of an exercise

Tags: c++, c++11, fatal-error

on the last test of an exercise it says "caught fatal signal 11"....my first thought was that the number of elements is too high bc it says the maximum "n" is 9 digits, but if I add another 0 to the vector (like "1000001" instead of "100001") it gives me the "caught fatal signal 11" on every test (because the vector elements number is too high).... so i don t know what to do

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
ifstream f("pozmax.in");
ofstream g("pozmax.out");
double v[100001];
int i, n, dif, difmax, k,maxi;
int main()
{

    f>> n;
    maxi=-99999999;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        f>> v[i];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if(v[i]>maxi)
            maxi=v[i];

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if(v[i]==maxi)
            {k=i;
                break;}
    g<<k<<" ";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if(v[i]==maxi)
            k=i;

    g<< k;


    f.close();
    g.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Array indices start from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: if i go from 1 to <=n or 0 to <n it is the same thing

Comment: It's not the same thing if you're using `v[i]`, though.

Comment: You can use [Valgrind](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/6e6f6d1b-95c3-46df-8a26-b7efd8ee4b57/entry/detect_memory_leaks_with_memcheck_tool_provided_by_valgrind_part_i8?lang=en) to diagnose segfault errors

Comment: You mean it crashes regardless? Or you're saying this shouldn't change anything?

Comment: I think you need to range check `n` to make sure it doesn't go outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: No, it doesn t crash, but the fatal signal 11 only appears in one online complier like the one an contest is having; codeblocks has something that avoids this error

Comment: This is C++. Please use `std::vector` instead of a fixed-size C array. You won't have to figure out the size in advance, and you can't overflow it on inserts. You should also look at using iterators instead of index-based `for` loops, these avoid a lot of off-by-one errors.

Comment: *"doesn t crash"* 'fatal signal 11' Is basically a crash.

Comment: Also make sure your files `f` and `g` are opening successfully.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's precisely a crash as signal 11 is a segmentation violation (SIGSEGV).

Comment: on the codeblocks it runs ok, it gives me the right answer but when i put the code into an online compiler to know if i have 100 or 0 points at that problem it tells me "Caught fatal signal 11", that s what i mean

Comment: yea, they are oppening successfully

Comment: I have a feeling this code could be boiled down to a handful of lines that basically runs [`max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) on a Standard Library container.

Comment: i just think that the "double" type allocates more locations of memory, like for 3.14 it allocates 4 locations(for 3 . 1 4) and it can not work well with 9 digit numbers

Comment: @MisterAdrian Not at all. That uses a [well known floating point format, IEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) on most architectures. A double can handle numbers a lot bigger than nine digits.

Comment: probably the big double type numbers are not meant to be putten in a vector idk

Comment: Why is `maxi` an `int` instead of a `double`?

Comment: `std::vector<double>` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @MisterAdrian Now you're starting to border on complete paranoia. An introduction to how C++ operates internally may help clear things up here. While templates and such can be complex, the basics of C++ are not that hard to understand and share a lot of commonality with C. There's only dark mysteries involved when you don't know the principles at work, but the good news is getting up to speed on those isn't that difficult. There's surely innumerable YouTube videos on the subject of the Intel Instruction Set Architecture.

Comment: oh,yeah, maxi should be double , but the error still persists

Comment: The only crash-inducing thing I see here is the wrong loop bounds. Are you saying changing all of them to `0`, `< n` didn't work?

Comment: nope, it didn't

Comment: Definitely add checks in your code that both files are opened successfully and that `n` is within the range of your array (0-100000).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is quite simple.
You're exceeding the max stack size.
By multiplying your double array size you're increasing the require size in bytes as well.
From 100001 * 8 => ~0.76MB up to ~7.63MB which exceeds most of all systems default stack size.
More details about the stack size could be read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1826072/10503293

A simple solution would be to allocate the array on the heap like:

```
double* v = new double[1000001];
... code ...
delete[] v;
```