# program crash in filling array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am getting a program crash specifically due to this part of my code where I fill an array. Even if I do it with a vector, I'm getting a crash.

```
long long a[200000000]{0,1};
for(long long i{2};i<200000000;i++){
    a[i]=a[i-1]+i;
}
```

OR

```
vector<int> a;
a.push_back(0);
a.push_back(1);
for(long long i{2};i<200000000;i++){
a.push_back(a.back()+i);
}
```

I'm using devC++.

Comment: The first one is a stack overflow. The second one may not crash

Comment: The second one takes about 10s and uses 1.7GB of memory on my machine, but it runs fine.

Comment: The first one wants an awful lot of stack. I am pretty sure your os does not hand that out and refuses to run your program.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program

Comment: Remember the default stack size is usually less than 10 MB depending on your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one uses a vector that allocates the memory you specify on a heap. If enough memory is available,then it should work fine.
It is not entirely clear whether the first code snippet is inside a function, but if it is, then you are most likely overflowing the stack.