# How to prevent stackoverflow error when working with large array? C

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I have code to sort 60000 lines into arrays for each data type

It worked for 1 line but when looping through many lines I get stack overflow error.

This is how I defined structs.

```
int main(void) {

typedef struct values{
    struct values* Time;
    struct values* RESP;
    struct values* PLETH;
    struct values* II;
    struct values* V;
    struct values* AVR;
    struct values* ABP;     
}values;

    values array[60000];
```

Here is a sample of the data file

[image]

Here is the code I used to read the file.

```
char line[80];
FILE* pointer = fopen("bidmc_04_Signals.csv", "r");
fgets(line, 60000, pointer);//moves pointer past 1st line
printf(line); 
fgets(line, 60000, pointer);
printf(line);
```

Here is the array generation part of my code

```
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int row_count = 0;
    int row_limit = 60000;
        while (row_count < row_limit) {
            fgets(line, 60, pointer);
            char*p = strtok(line, ",");
            c = 0;
            while (p != NULL)
            {               
                if (c == 0)
                    strcpy(array[i].Time, p);
                    array[i].Time = malloc(10000);

                if (c == 1)
                    strcpy(array[i].RESP, p);
                    array[i].RESP = malloc(10000);

                if (c == 2)
                    strcpy(array[i].PLETH, p);
                    array[i].PLETH = malloc(10000);

                if (c == 3)
                    strcpy(array[i].II, p);
                    array[i].II = malloc(10000);

                if (c == 4)
                    strcpy(array[i].V, p);
                    array[i].V = malloc(10000);

                if (c == 5)
                    strcpy(array[i].AVR, p);
                    array[i].AVR = malloc(10000);

                if (c == 6)
                    strcpy(array[i].ABP, p);
                    array[i].ABP = malloc(10000);

                p = strtok(NULL, ",");
                c++;
                }

            row_count++;
            i++;        
        }
        
    fclose(pointer);
    for (i = 0; i < 60000; i++) {
    
    free(array[i].RESP);
    free(array[i].PLETH);
    free(array[i].II);
    free(array[i].V);
    free(array[i].AVR);
    free(array[i].ABP);
}

}
```

As you can see I tried using malloc() to move array data to heap but it didn't work.
How do I prevent the code from getting a stack overflow error?

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain what `array` is, because as it stands, there is no large array allocated on the stack here.

Comment: Note that a thread has a limited stack size of a few MB (see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64085509/4561887). So, for really large objects, you must dynamically allocate onto the heap.

Comment: When asking for help with code, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see exactly what is going on and so we can try it ourselves. From what we _can_ see, you certainly have memory errors (`malloc(10000)` when `sizeof values` is probably 56 :( ) which can literally result in anything happening.

Comment: Better to post text as text than as a picture.

Comment: Note that `strcpy(array[i].Time, p);  array[i].Time = malloc(10000);` are **not** part of the  `if (c == 0)`. Only `strcpy(array[i].Time, p);` is part of the `if()` block.

Comment: Aside: `printf(line);` is considered dangerous, and opens the code to malicious exploits – the data could contain format specifiers. Please use `printf("%s", line);`

Comment: In addition to the [mcve], run your code through an autoindenter or autoformatter. You'll be surprised.

Answer (score 2):

### Use more [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

[Call stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) are typically limited to a megabyte and contain your [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)s. Your call frame (for your `array`) is huge, and you probably have a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

You need to use [calloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3.html) for your array and declare it as `value*array;` (of course, change the name, it becomes a pointer, not an array).

So

```
 value*ptr = calloc(60000, sizeof(value));
 if (!ptr) { perror("calloc failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

then use `ptr` instead of `array`. Be aware that [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and `calloc` can fail. See also [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).

Don't forget to `free(ptr)` when it is not needed.

#### Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and take inspiration from *existing* open source software,

like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/). Read also some draft C standard, e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

**Read also carefully the documentation of your C compiler**, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) **and of your debugger**, e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). If you can use GCC, compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get several warnings, and perhaps even with [`-fanalyzer`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) and other options, such as `-Wstack-usage=2048`

Consider using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

On Linux, [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) could be helpful, in addition of [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html). You could also consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/).

> I have code to sort 60000 lines ...

Then consider using [qsort(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) or `qsort_r`

Read also a good [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

PS. You might be interested in [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (see [this draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf)) & in [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/). In both cases, contact me by email (in English, or French, or Russian) to `basile@starynkevitch.net`

Comment: just tried what you proposed, the memory in stack has gone down. But new error :file access violation.

Comment: Yes, you need to learn programming. Budget months of efforts.

Comment: ok thanks for the resources and the help

Answer (score 1):

In addition to another answer, these lines (and the 5 other similar sets)

```
if (c == 0)
    strcpy(array[i].Time, p);
    array[i].Time = malloc(10000);
```

are lacking braces, are the wrong way round, and allocates excessive memory. Please change to

```
if (c == 0) {             // indentation alone does not make a code block
    array[i].Time = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);   // allocate the right amount
    strcpy(array[i].Time, p);                // AFTER allocation
}
```

Also these two lines

```
fgets(line, 60000, pointer); 
...
fgets(line, 60, pointer);
```

should both be

```
fgets(line, sizeof line, pointer);
```