# Cannot produce any output on increasing size of arr of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I m using **minGW compiler** along with **VScode** on **windows 10**

Problem I m facing is provided below :

here I can see output while using an **arr of vectors of size 1500**

```
Hello World
Execution works
```

[image]

.

.

.

But on declaring an **arr of vectors** of large size I cannot receive any output in terminal
[image]

How will I be able o work with an arr of vectors of size 150000 or more ?

Comment: You're running out of stack with big arrays ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program)).

Comment: @AnoopRana the OP intentionally wants array of vectors.

Comment: You can create dynamically on heap instead of stack with new operator and/or any smart pointers.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) reads: *DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.*

Comment: @Evg I will definitely take care of this in future.

Comment: this is question N where they want 150000 vectors of vectors, what is the problem they want to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You blew up the stack. Every `std::vector` object occupies **24** bytes on the stack (in GCC's implementation). Now *150000 * 24* = **3.6** MB which may easily cause a problem for you.

Instead, try this (one of the easiest ways):

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v( 150'000 );
```

or maybe this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v( 150'000, std::vector<int>( 1000 ) );
```

The above statement will create a vector that owns 150000 other vectors each of which has 1000 elements initialized to 0.

Comment: Or just `v( 150'000 );`

Comment: @Evg Right. Added that.

Comment: @digito_evo thnx for helping, btw in using VScode + minGW compiler, so by editing what settings in VScode can I have the stack size increase upto 5 MB ?

Comment: @user14106566 There are a few factors that determine the stack size of a program. It can not be done just by editing settings in VS Code (VS code is just an editor). Nonetheless, similar questions have been asked on this site several times. You can read their answers. You may also search on Google and find a good answer for that.