# Randon Name Generator won't work, even though I fixed all issues

Tags: c

It doesn't put the correct amount of array elements, and reads less than supposed to and when 1 becomes true it spits either NULL, or 0.
becomes true it doesn't print the random name

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char cast1;
    int cast2;

    printf("Choose array length: ");
    scanf("%c", &cast1);
    cast2 = atoi(&cast1);
    char parr1[cast2];

    for(i=0; i<cast1; i++)
    {
        char tempchar;
        printf("Name to insert to array: ");
        scanf("%s", &tempchar);
        parr1[i] = tempchar;
    }

    int range = sizeof(parr1) / sizeof(parr1[0]);
    int tempint;
    int logic;
    char answer;

    printf("Would you like to generate a new name?[y1/n2]: ");
    scanf("%d", &logic);
    if(logic==1)
    {
        answer='y';
    }
    else if(logic==2)
    {
        answer='n';
    }

    while(answer=='y')
    {
        tempint = rand()%range;
        printf("%c", parr1[tempint]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never update `answer` in the `while` loop, so it's an infinite loop.

Comment: `atoi` expects a string; maybe you meant to use `cast2 = cast1 - '0';`.

Comment: Your `atoi` call has undefined behavior, since you're passing it a pointer to a single character, which is not guaranteed to be followed by a null character.  You need to pass it the address of a null-terminated character array, not a single character.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &cast1); cast2 = atoi(&cast1);` Why not just `scanf("%d", &cast2)`?

Comment: Why are you reading just a single character for the array length?

Comment: `%s` requires the argument to be a pointer to a character array. You're passing a pointer to a single `char`, which doesn't have room for the null terminator.

Comment: Not checking the return value of `scanf` is always a bug. Also, where is the random name?

Comment: I would recommend to read some C tutorials on strings, arrays, pointers.  Too many problems with this code

Comment: using an incorrect format specifier in `scanf` or `printf` is always a source of [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).  For this reason alone, your code contains several opportunities for unwanted randomness, which is partly preventing the desired randomness you are attempting.  Adding to that that `srand` is not being called.  This too will cause `rand` to be even less random than it normally is.

Comment: I see the user asked for a name and then it spits back the same name. Are you sure it's doing what you intend? Technically, that isn't really [random](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269448).

Answer (score 0):

The comments have highlighted many issues. Here are some of the same, some more, and some solutions.

The `const char *` argument to `atoi` does not mean a pointer to any character, but rather a pointer to a null-terminated sequence of non-zero bytes: a [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

On `scanf`, briefly:

- Always check the return value is the *expected number of conversions*. Failing to do so means operating on indeterminate values.
- `%d` reads a signed integer, `%u` reads an unsigned integer.
- `%c` reads a single character. Prefixing this specifier with a space ( `%c`) causes it to [skip leading whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/2505965).
- `%s` reads a [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). Its argument must be a pointer to a buffer that can store multiple characters, with room for a null-terminating byte (hint: an array). Always limit this specifier to the size of the buffer, minus one.

```
char buffer[128];
if (1 != scanf("%127s", buffer))
   /* uh oh */;
```

Had it worked, `char parr1[cast2];` would only be able to a single [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). You need an array of arrays to store multiple strings.

When creating a [variable-length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays), care must be taken to ensure the size is always a positive, non-zero integer that will not expend too much [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825964/2505965).

Calling `rand` without first calling `srand` ([once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/2505965)) will lead to the same results every time you run the program.

Reading an integer (`scanf("%d", &logic);`), and then using that value to determine the value of another variable (`answer`), only to use the second value the same way you would have used the first is ... redundant.

`while(answer=='y')` will never stop, as `answer` does not change inside the loop.

---

This is, more-or-less, the program you were attempting to write.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned length;

    printf("Choose array length: ");

    if (1 != scanf("%u", &length) || 0 == length || length > 50)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    char names[length][100];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("Name to insert to array: ");

        if (1 != scanf("%99s", names[i]))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    while (1) {
        char answer;

        printf("Would you like to generate a new name? (y1 / n2): ");

        if (1 != scanf(" %c", &answer))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        if (!strchr("y1", answer))
            break;

        puts(names[(unsigned) rand() % length]);
    }
}
```

Input file for testing (`./a.out < input`):

```
10
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyn
```

Output, abbreviated:

```
Would you like to generate a new name? (y1 / n2): one
Would you like to generate a new name? (y1 / n2): four
Would you like to generate a new name? (y1 / n2): nine
Would you like to generate a new name? (y1 / n2): ten
Would you like to generate a new name? (y1 / n2): five
Would you like to generate a new name? (y1 / n2): one
Would you like to generate a new name? (y1 / n2): seven
...
```